# Iterating over a Python generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I'm trying to write a function that will take as input a string of intervals e.g `"0-0,4-8,20-21,43-45"` to produce all numbers within each of the ranges meaning: `[0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 20, 21, 43, 44, 45]`

The exercise requires to do so using generators. I managed to parse the input through a generator but I can't do the same for populating the numbers. I'm trying to `int()` each number so I could leverage the `range()` to produce all numbers within the edges.

Here's my conceptual code - how can I produce the numbers within each interval?

```
def parse_ranges(arg):
    arg = arg.split(",")
    parsed= (line.split("-") for line in arg)

    #Trying to parse each character to int to use range()
    intervals= (int(i) for i in number for number in parsed)

    # Even if I had the characters parsed to int, I still don't know how to produce the range
    ranges = (range(interval[0],interval[1]) interval for interval in intervals)
    return ranges

print(list(parse_ranges("0-0,4-8,20-21,43-45")))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def parse_ranges(arg):
    arg = arg.split(",")
    parsed = ((line.split("-")) for line in arg)

    for pair in parsed:
        yield from range(int(pair[0]), int(pair[1])+1)

print(list(parse_ranges("0-0,4-8,20-21,43-45")))

Out: [0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 20, 21, 43, 44, 45]
```

If you want to pass values from a generator INSIDE another generator directly out to the consumer of the outer generator, you need to use the "[yield from](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr)" expression. (Also, note that you need to extend the "to" end of each range by +1, since the range endpoint is not inclusive.)

Answer (score 0):

Two pieces that you seem to missing are: the second argument of `range()` needs to be one beyond what you want; you can pass control from one generator to another via `yield from`:

```
def parse_ranges(arg):
    for start, stop in (interval.split('-') for interval in arg.split(',')):
        yield from range(int(start), int(stop) + 1)

print(*parse_ranges("0-0,4-8,20-21,43-45"))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
0 4 5 6 7 8 20 21 43 44 45
%
```